# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, ntlm

This is driving me crazy.
I'm trying to access a WCF service via an ASP.NET web form,
I'm setting the binding for the `channelfactory` up like this:

```cs
BasicHttpBinding b = null;

if (Communication.SlServiceURL.StartsWith("https"))
    b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
else
{
    b = new BasicHttpBinding();
    b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
}

b.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
b.Security.Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm, ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None };
b.Security.Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity { ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName };
```

Then I create a new Channel Wrapper via:

```cs
public ClientChannelWrapper(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
{
    m_Factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, remoteAddress);
}
```

I'm passing the binding and a https://[myservice]/myservice.svc URL as the `remoteAddress`.

The thing is: When I call the service in my production server with IIS 7, Windows Authentication enabled on the site and ONLY "NTLM" as the provider for the authentication, everything else disabled (no anonymous, forms, etc.)
I get the exception:

> Exception type: MessageSecurityException
>
> Exception message: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

This is pretty weird and I can't seem to find a way around this. I have also a *Silverlight* application hosted in another ASP.NET Form and there it works fine with this binding which is freaking me out because why wouldn't the same thing work in the ASP.NET site hosted in the same IIS site.

Also strange: When firing the site up from Visual Studio with F5 it works when accessing the production WCF service in the IIS7 machine. As soon as I deploy the site I get the exception.

Edit: It's clear now why *Silverlight* behaves different than ASP.NET, since *Silverlight* is communicating directly via the client computer with the service. Still no luck with the exception.